# VueJS Loop through Incrementing Component Name Prefixes

Tags: loops, components, vuejs2

I have a VueJS application which is a multi-step form, each step of the form is a new component as they each contain different logic, views, scripts and styles.

I have named the components, `section1`, `section2`, `section3` etc.. The data passed from the parent, `applicationForm` component remains a similar style, `:errors="errors.section1" :warnings="warnings.section1" :form-data-"formData.section1"`

My thought was instead of duplicating code and changing the numerical section number each time, if I could put it into a `for loop` to make it easier to manage. So the below:

```
<section1 v-if="(step == 1)" class="relative" :errors="errors.section1 || {}" :warnings="warnings.section1 || {}" :form-data="formData.sections.section1 || {}" :user="user"></section1>
<section2 v-if="(step == 2)" class="relative" :errors="errors.section2 || {}" :warnings="warnings.section2 || {}" :form-data="formData.sections.section2 || {}" :user="user"></section2>
<section3 v-if="(step == 3)" class="relative" :errors="errors.section3 || {}" :warnings="warnings.section3 || {}" :form-data="formData.sections.section3 || {}" :user="user"></section3>
<section3 v-if="(step == 4)" class="relative" :errors="errors.section4 || {}" :warnings="warnings.section4 || {}" :form-data="formData.sections.section4 || {}" :user="user"></section3>
<section3 v-if="(step == 5)" class="relative" :errors="errors.section5 || {}" :warnings="warnings.section5 || {}" :form-data="formData.sections.section5 || {}" :user="user"></section3>
<section3 v-if="(step == 6)" class="relative" :errors="errors.section6 || {}" :warnings="warnings.section6 || {}" :form-data="formData.sections.section6 || {}" :user="user"></section3>
<section3 v-if="(step == 7)" class="relative" :errors="errors.section7 || {}" :warnings="warnings.section7 || {}" :form-data="formData.sections.section7 || {}" :user="user"></section3>
<section3 v-if="(step == 8)" class="relative" :errors="errors.section8 || {}" :warnings="warnings.section8 || {}" :form-data="formData.sections.section8 || {}" :user="user"></section3>
```

Is transformed into something like (I don't know the correct approach however):

```
<section{n} v-for="n in 8" class="relative" :errors="errors.section{n} || {}" :warnings="warnings.section{n} || {}" :form-data="formData.sections.section{n} || {}" :user="user"></section1>
```

Is this possible? Or due to how the `data` object is used, it isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the reserved `<component>` element with `:is` attribute.

Read more about [Dynamic Component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

You need to do this way,

```
<component v-for="n in 8" :is="'section'+n" class="relative" :error="errors['section'+n] || {}" :warnings="warnings['section'+n] || {}" :form-data="formData.sections['section'+n] || {}" :user="user"></component>
```

- `<component>` is a reserved component element to load components dynamically
- `:is="'section'+n"` - `is` is attribute used for dynamic component.
- `:error="errors['section'+n]` - use this way to bind variables for `section1`, `section2`...

Here's a small demo which works as expected,
https://codepen.io/mkumaran/pen/VWQdor

```js
Vue.component('section1', {
  props: ['error'],
  template: `
   <div>
    <h2>This is section1</h2>
    <span>{{error.message}}</span>
  </div>`
});
Vue.component('section2', {
  props: ['error'],
  template: `
  <div>
    <h2>This is section2</h2>
    <span>{{error.message}}</span>
  </div>`
});
Vue.component('section3', {
  props: ['error'],
  template: `
  <div>
    <h2>This is section3</h2>
    <span>{{error.message}}</span>
  </div>`
});
Vue.component('section4', {
  props: ['error'],
  template: `
  <div>
    <h2>This is section4</h2>
    <span>{{error.message}}</span>
  </div>`
});
Vue.component('section5', {
  props: ['error'],
  template: `
  <div>
    <h2>This is section5</h2>
    <span>{{error.message}}</span>
  </div>`
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
    errors: {
      section1: {
        message: 'section1 error'
      },
      section2: {
        message: 'section2 error'
      },
      
      section4: {
        message: 'section4 error'
      },
      section5: {
        message: 'section5 error'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
span{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <component v-for="n in 5" :is="'section'+n" :error="errors['section'+n] || {}"></component>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but this won't achieve using different components for the different parts of the multi-step form. I would still require a way to use the other components, `<section1>`, `<section2>` etc.. I could perhaps use the `render` method to do it programmatically.

Comment: Sorry my mistake.. it's possible to do.. will update my answer shortly

Comment: I see, so you can use the `is` directive on `component` to set the component to load. That's useful. Thanks

Comment: A follow up, this worked really well. Thanks, I've marked as answer